# Grails Spring Security Configuration thru xml

Tags: security, spring, grails, ldap

i am new at grails spring security, and i wanted to know if it is possible to enable/disable security of in my app thru an xml entry.

rather than having
grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = true

I d like to read the value from a bean that i declared in my resources.xml file.

grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = com.myorg.util.BeanUtil.getBean("repositorySettings").getIsSecured()

Using this approach throws errors. is there a way that i can accomplish this, and read the true/false value from a bean in the resources.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat possible. `resources.xml` and `resources.groovy` are loaded after the plugin is, but parsed before. So you can put code in `resources.groovy` that will run while it's being parsed, before the plugin loads the config, and determines whether it's enabled. But you can't use a bean for that since it wouldn't be ready until it's too late. This wouldn't be possible in `resources.xml` since that's just XML but `resources.groovy` allows Groovy code and bean definitions:

```
import com.pbbi.mimgr.util.BeanUtil

beans = {
   def grailsApplication = springConfig.unrefreshedApplicationContext.grailsApplication
   def securityConfig = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity
   securityConfig.active = BeanUtil.getBean('repositorySettings').isSecured
}
```

If `BeanUtil` accesses the `ApplicationContext` then this won't work. But if it's accessing singletons that aren't Spring beans it should be fine.

Comment: Great. Thanks i got it too work. i can read configuration from outside the config.groovy.  But when securityConfig.active equals false i get this error:
Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined.  
This error does not occur when .active equals false, and it was set in the Config.groovy. Any Ideas ???